# How to shake input boxes on click

Tags: jquery

**My Jquery**

```
$(".skip").click(function () {
  $('input.inputbox').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 300);
});
```

**my html**

```
<div class="ce-cf-container">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inputbox" value="">
</div>

<button class="skip" >Contact us now to gain financial freedom quicker</button>
```

What I want to do is, once someone clicks on the `button` I want to shake the input box. Why isnt my code working?

Comment: i tried `button.skip` too. but no luck

Comment: have you include jquery-ui.min.js? because your code works fine for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to include `jQuery UI` to make use of `effect()` as it is not available on `jQuery` standalone.

Insert the jQuery UI script after your jQuery script and it will start working:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've created a working Fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/pQvEk/

Comment: Could be a problem with the jQuery version you're using. I see there's a missing method error on the page. Try updating jQuery to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="ce-cf-container">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inputbox" value="">
</div>
<input type="button" class="skip" value="Contact us now to gain financial freedom quicker" />
```

Actually

```
<button class="skip" >Contact us now to gain financial freedom quicker</button>
```

that you have has a submit behavior which submits and refreshes the page so you can't see the effect happening.

**UPDATE**

I have used this script reference

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No. It doesnt have a submit feature and the page isnt refreshing.